# how to crack RandomUtils.nextInt(a,b) by knowing some num seq

Tags: random

for example,
These three values (79,81,98) come from org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(2,101) ,
how can I get the seed and predict the following numbers ?

Comment: Start by having a look at the source code to work out what RNG Apache is using.  Then research how to break that particular RNG.

Comment: it use Java Random class indeed looks like start + Random.nextInt(end -start).
I found some crack method for Random.nextInt() on the internet, but it shows no solutions for this one.

Comment: If you know what `end` and `start` are you can rework the equation to solve for `Random.nextInt()`

Comment: @rossum Embarrassed because i dont really know how to do with it. the solutions on the internet is for no-parameter method.

Comment: See how the no-parameter version is used inside the parameter version.  Work backwards from that.

Comment: I tried， but failed